# How do you set up Webstorm 6.0 to breakpoint debug a nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have not found a good simple tutorial for this. I just want the app to freeze at the breakpoints so I can explore the contents of the various variables, particularly their json content.

This is a garbage documentation:
http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#d40161e701

I can't even set up breakpoints. Is it so simple to do this in Eclipse...

**UPDATE**
Using Webstorm 7.0's early access build, the debugger works flawlessly. I just made a new project, added a breakpoint and used Debug. Stopped at that breakpoint with no problems whatsoever, so apparently Webstorm 6.0's debugger sucks :D

You can get it here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+7+EAP Beware, it expires on 8 August.

Comment: Do you know if WebStorm 7 can also debug node.js apps written in CoffeeScript?

Comment: I think yes, there is CoffeeScript stuff inside the settings :D

Answer (score 0):

I use webstorm and it's great. Having looked at that documentation, I agree. If you're just starting out, you don't need all the remote and attach to existing processes options.

The easiest option would be to rightclick on your main js file and choose debug. Setting breakpoints is the same as in most editors these days, just click left of the line.

If you don't get the debug option when you right click then you need to make a run/debug configuration which sounds worse than it is.

1. Select "Run" -> "Edit configurations".
2. Click the plus sign.
3. Choose "Node.js"
4. Click on the browse ... button on the Path to Node App js file and choose the file you want to debug
5. Click Ok.
6. Click on the bug!

Comment: I can't add a breakpoint! most of the options on the dropdown are disabled :|

Comment: That doesnt' sound right... so you have a js file open and can't set a breakpoint anywhere? What options are disabled? When you press the plus sign?

Comment: Having a js file open or not does not sound like something I would have a problem with :| Like asking a person with internet if he has the PC powered on or not. Only the "view breakpoints" option is available and inside it, "all exceptions" are ticked on. If I debug my main js, it gets suspended on various parts inside the nodejs library, stuff like bind, etc. I only want it to suspend on MY breakpoints.

Comment: I managed to add breakpoints but it ignores them. Furthermore, it suspends each time a function is called, in my js. This behaviour is undocumented, from what I can research. Apparently webstorm 7.0 has a new / different debugger for nodejs (or javascript) and I will wait for it to be released (its beta i think).

Comment: odd. I did have the issue where it stops on filesystem operations inside of node which is solved by turning off the Exception Breakpoints. I suggest you contact their support if it doesn't work for you. Surprised they haven't picked up your post here on SO